# displaying multiple view files on a single page -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails plugin, i want to display multiple view files onto a single page.

Say i want to append some view after the index view.

i am using

```
<% render :partial => "show" %>
```

in my index.erb

It works fine. But for better design I want to do the same thing from controller.

So, if i write in my contoller inside the index action

```
render :partial => "show"
```

only the show file gets rendered on the page.

Cant I use multiple partials?

Any comments/suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it would be more 'true' to the MVC architecture if that logic remained in the view. I think the cleanest way to do this is to include the partials in your index view using render like you've already done.

As far as I'm aware, you cannot 'append' views/partials to one another from the controller.

Comment: okay..  i will check more. other wise will use the current way. thnx for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this I added my three show page view partials

```html
_storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase1
_storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase2
_storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase3
```

to my orders controller. I did this by running a migration

```html
rails generate migration AddChose_Parital_Show_View_ToListings ordershowviewpartialoption:string
```

and adding a collection select to my listing controller.

```html
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ordershowviewpartialoption %>
     <%= f.select :WHAT THE USER SEES IN THE DROP DOWN MENU FOR PARTIAL SHOW VIEW OPTION 2, [['Tictactoe Game', 
'storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase1'],

['WHAT THE USER SEES IN THE DROP DOWN MENU FOR PARTIAL SHOW VIEW OPTION 2',
'storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase2'], 

['WHAT THE USER SEES IN THE DROP DOWN MENU FOR PARTIAL SHOW VIEW OPTION 3',
'storethenameofparitalshowviewoptionindatabase3']], {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
  </div>
```

and don't forget in controllers\listings_controller.rb

```html
change this...

def listing_params
   params.require(:listing).permit(:AAA, :BBB, :CCC)
end

to this...

def listing_params
   params.require(:listing).permit(:AAA, :BBB, :CCC, :ordershowviewpartialoption)
end
```

in models\order.rb I have

```html
belongs_to :listings
```

in models\listing.rb I

```html
have has_many :orders
```

in my orders\show.html.erb

```html
<%= render @order.listing.ordershowviewpartialoption %>
```